Nestjs exception filter for GraphQLError
I have a GraphQL API created with Nestjs. When an incorrect input supplied to a mutation, getting ;
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Variable \"$input\" got invalid value -100 at \"input.population\"; Value is not a positive number: -100",
            "locations": [
                {
                    "line": 1,
                    "column": 21
                }
            ],
            "extensions": {
                "code": "BAD_USER_INPUT",
                "stacktrace": [
                    "GraphQLError: Value is not a positive number: -100",
                    "    at createGraphQLError (/Users/Development/nestjs-graphql/node_modules/graphql-scalars/cjs/error.js:9:12)",
                    "    at processValue (/Users/Development/nestjs-graphql/node_modules/graphql-scalars/cjs/scalars/utilities.js:101:49)",
                    "    at GraphQLScalarType.parseValue (/Users/Development/nestjs-graphql/node_modules/graphql-scalars/cjs/scalars/PositiveInt.js:14:48)",
                    "    at coerceInputValueImpl (/Users/Development/nestjs-graphql/node_modules/graphql/utilities/coerceInputValue.js:151:26)",
                    "    at coerceInputValueImpl (/Users/Development/nestjs-graphql/node_modules/graphql/utilities/coerceInputValue.js:117:34)",
                    "    at coerceInputValueImpl (/Users/Development/nestjs-graphql/node_modules/graphql/utilities/coerceInputValue.js:49:14)",
                    "    at coerceInputValue (/Users/Development/nestjs-graphql/node_modules/graphql/utilities/coerceInputValue.js:32:10)",
                    "    at coerceVariableValues (/Users/Development/nestjs-graphql/node_modules/graphql/execution/values.js:132:69)",
                    "    at getVariableValues (/Users/Development/nestjs-graphql/node_modules/graphql/execution/values.js:45:21)",
                    "    at buildExecutionContext (/Users/Development/nestjs-graphql/node_modules/graphql/execution/execute.js:280:63)"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}

Is it possible to create an exception filter to catch GraphQLError?

The error message clearly says that input.population should be greater than 0. Also if this is not the answer you were looking please share your query so that we can help you better.

I created the error deliberately. What I need is to be able to catch it in an exception filter.

Can you post you front-end and back-end code? Frontend where you are making the API request and Backend graphql schema. Also which backend language are you using?
